# fetch perticular number of documents satisfying multiple conditions - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch index for an information of fruits as below

```
GET fruits/fruits_data/_search

[{ id: 1,
   name: apple},
 { id: 2,
   name: mango},
 { id: 3,
   name: apple},
 { id: 4,
   name: banana},
 { id: 5,
   name: apple},
 { id: 6,
   name: mango},
 { id: 7,
   name: pineapple},
 { id: 8,
   name: jackfruit}]
```

Now I need to fetch `7` fruits as per the priority (below):

```
{"apple": 3, "banana": 3, "mango": 2, "guava": 2, "pineapple": 1, "jackfruit": 1}
```

Here the `key` indicates the fruit to be fetched and `value`indicates the maximum number of the document to be fetched.
This means I need to fetch maximum `3 apple, 3 banana and 1 mango` and I can ignore the others in priority hash when I have required number of fruits. But here I have only `1 banana` in my ES index so I need to fetch maximum `3 apple, 1 banana, 2 mango and 1 pineapple` (Since `guava` is not present in index we need to ignore it. 
Is there a way to fetch fruits like this in ES in a single query. I don't want to use multiple queries.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to fetch results directly,Try using `Aggregation` in elasticsearch. You can refer to link below,
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html]